# Module not found when using gunicorn (Python, Flask)

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am attempting to convert my Flask application to using a gunicorn server. Since I am using a Windows laptop, I have to deploy my app to Docker to test with gunicorn. The problem is, whenever I try to run the container, I get this error:
File "/service/app/server.py", line 4, in 
import db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'

The import statement in server.py for db.py doesn't work, even though they're in the same directory and it works when I am not using gunicorn.

Here is part of my dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app 
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers=3", "server:main"]
```

and my project structure:

```
\service
   \app
      server.py
      db.py
```

I tried to change the working directory in my dockerfile but it doesn't work.

Comment: before importing the db in your script, append the current path using `sys.path.append('.')`

Comment: I don't see how `WORKDIR /app` works, since you said the actual folder layout is `/service/app`

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to answer the question. How are you installing requirements in your Dockerfile? How are you copying your code into the image?

Comment: FROM python-image
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
USER root
COPY . /service
WORKDIR /service
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app 
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers=3", "server:main"]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run this command:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers=3", "server:app"]
```